# How to handle computer files in Genexus for reading, copying and deleting

Tags: genexus

I'm fairly new to genexus. I'm using a Genexus 17 trial. I created a procedure with the following code:

```
&file.Source="c:\abc123.txt"
&file.Create()
If &file.exists()
   &Text = "The file exists!"
Else 
   //&Text = &file.ErrDescription
   &Text =  &file.GetAbsoluteName()
   &i = &file.ErrCode 
EndIf

Print printBlock1
```

When I call the procedure, I get the result "c:\abc123.txt 0" in a pdf format because of the printBlock1 layout (&Text &i). `&file.exists()` always returns false, and after the call I can't find my file in the system. Why doesn't genexus create the file?

Comment: ¿What environment are you using? If its web, you can´t create files on C: . If not, you should check security in the folder/disk you want to create the file.

Comment: Yes, its in web. The only option is creating a file for download then?

Comment: Code running in the browser has no access to the client machines resource, including the file system, it is a matter of security. Your code can't read files in the client file system, so a way to solve this is create the file in the application path and let the user download it.

Comment: @GuidoLorenzatti Do you know how to change deployment from web to desktop? I'm using the Genexus 17 desktop IDE. When I run the developer menu the program is deployed in the genexus cloud.

Comment: Maybe you should create a new Environment with User Interface: Windows https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7115,Category%3AEnvironments